# How to show a page URL from a different domain and server in a iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I would like to make this question even if I am almost sure to know the answer. Is it possible to do what described in subject?

When I tried that, Chrome didn't display the page html, but only a bank white space with an error. I read what explained here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Is it correct that the page I want to display must have this parameter set server side in its web server? Is there anything I can do client side in my html code?

Comment: Yes, the remote site must allow any such framing. No, there is nothing you can do about this client-side - if there was, then the introduction of this measure would have been pointless to begin with - to let the other site decide whether it wants to allow what you are trying to do or not, is the whole purpose here to begin with. (Nothing, with the exception that this can be circumvented by a browser extension - that way it would work, if you only need this locally for your own tests ... but not in the general context of a website the user visits in their browser.)

Comment: Click F12 and see if there is an error in the console. For example google will not allow itself to be framed

Comment: @CBroe thanks a lot for the brilliant answer!

Comment: @mplungjan yes I have that error!

Comment: Then you are SOL unless you use a proxy which is very likely against their TOS - that makes you TOSSOL ;)

Comment: What do SOL and TOS mean? Is it something about same origin etc.. ?

Comment: "Shit Outta Luck" and "Terms of Service"

Comment: Lol, I'll use the method local page and addon...it is just a demo at the end...